# How to allow new line by pressing Return Key C#, like text editor. Console application

Tags: c#, console-application, streamwriter

this is my first here :)

I was wondering if is it possible to interpret "Enter/Return" key as New Line like using it in a textarea.

Like using a text editor

```
try
{
    Console.WriteLine("Type to write..");
    streamw.WriteLine(Console.ReadLine());
    streamw.Close();
} 
[..]
```

In this situation up here.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: After you read multiple lines then how would you close the application?

Answer (score 0):

You could create an escape code so you don't close your reader until the escape code is entered by the user.

For example, consider the following code

```
Console.WriteLine("Type to write..");
while(true){
    string line = Console.ReadLine(); // Read our user input
    if(line.Equals("END")) break; // If our user enters 'END' stop reading and exit the while loop
    streamw.WriteLine(line); // Otherwise, we write our line and carry on reading input
}    
streamw.Close();
```

In the above code we keep getting line after line until the user types `END`.